# 1st homebrew, how long to be ready? Any support and better recipes

Tags: fermentation-temperature, alcohol-content

I'm trying to make my Homebrew with the following materials:

- 8 l non-alcoholic beer
- 1 tea spoon of yeast
- 1 kg sugar

I have mixed them in carboy with airlock inside a dark room.

The question is, how long do I have to wait for fermentation?
And within 30 days, is it ready to drink or are there other steps?

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can homebrew stay in the primary fermenter?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/how-long-can-homebrew-stay-in-the-primary-fermenter)

Comment: I have read the question that you mentioned thnk you for your comment.

Comment: The best way to make beer is from beer-making ingredients.  (I would never have guessed that someone would try to make beer from other beer!)  Do you not have access to malt and hops where you live?

Comment: There is malts but I’m trying to find hops it’s not available in hole country

Comment: there are other herbs that will add bitterness to the beer if hops not are not available, like yarrow, mugwort, tea..... https://www.brewersofpa.org/alternatives-to-hops/

Comment: Fermenting sugar is at best nothing but adding just alcohol. You may as well just buy some vodka and spike your non-alcoholic beer with a very small shot - for all practical purposes, it's even better than what you're trying to do currently. If you're after not specifically beer, but affordable booze (I totally understand you on this!), check out mead and ciders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of hard to answer your question without knowing where you are. That said, if you're trying to convert non-alcohol beer by adding sugar and yeast, it's pretty doubtful that you'll be all that happy with the results. As far as I'm concerned, it'll never be ready to drink.

If you tell us where you are, I'll edit this to reflect a much better solution.

Edited to reflect where the OP lives.

Since you can get barley and yeast, you may want to look into using other herbs.  I've had enjoyable beers made with basil and rosemary.  Rosemary will give it a flavor profile very similar to some of the hops with a "piney" flavor. Also, I know of one brew shop online who ships overseas (at least to service members), you may want to check out LabelPeelers.com .

I would caution you to use malted barley.  The barley that you use for soups would be unsuitable. The yeast used to make bread is the exact same species as that which is used for making ale.  The only difference is that yeast for ale has "grown up" in an ale like environment, so if you can't get yeast, it'll work.

Comment: I’m in Bamako the cabital of Mali (West Africa) the good alcoholic beverages are very expensive so that’s why I wanna make my own homebrew :)

Comment: Do you have access to beer ingredients such as malted barley or wheat, hops and yeast? If not, is it easy to get some honey? If so, you could make mead. You'll still need some good yeast strain, but much less ingredients.

Comment: Honey, yeast and malt are easy to find but the problem with hops, nobody use it here and no way to get it. So can I brewing without hops?

Comment: You can certainly brew without hops. Hundreds of years ago, beer without hops was called ale. People would add all different kinds of herbs as flavorings and for bittering. I am sure you have access to several kinds of herbs. Are there any herbs that you enjoy that could serve as substitutes for hops? Use small amounts, about 2 to 5 grams per gallon, boiled in the raw beer wort for 30 minutes or less, or make a tea with them, then add the herb tea to the beer. The herbs can also help add preservative qualities to the finished product. But do not be surprised if it also has a slight tartness.

Comment: That should be your quesiton. "I live in Mali. We don't have homebrew shops or the ingredients you guys do, how can I brew?"

Comment: Also, you might want to check out this website on non hopped beers. They are called Gruit. http://www.gruitale.com/intro_en.htm

Answer (score -1):

Most of your questions will be answered if you take a look at this : [How To Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/)

In general, one week is enough to ferment a batch, and 2 weeks before bottling is enough to get a clear "ish" beer.  You can let it sit for a longer time if you want.  After you can bottle condition which adds about one week to the process, and after you will be able to drink it.

However, as CharlieHorse mentionned, you might not be very pleased with the results, but you will see.